# How do you refresh JavaFX scene from inside an button action?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a sorting algorithm visualizer and i want the UI to update in real time to show how it works, step by step.

But the UI only updates when the sort() method is done, I want it to update when updateHeight() is done

the sort() method is initiated by an onAction

```
   @FXML
public void sort() throws InterruptedException {
    minHeight = RectHeight[0];
    counter = 0;
    minIndex = 0;
    temp = 0;

    for(int i=1;i<RectList.size();i++){
        System.out.println(RectList.size());
        System.out.println(counter);
        sort2();
    }


}
public void sort2() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("start sort");

    System.out.println(minHeight);



    System.out.println("find min");
    for (int i = counter; i < (RectList.size()); i++) {
        System.out.println("i= " + i);
        if (RectHeight[i] < minHeight) {
            minHeight = RectHeight[i];
            System.out.println("minHeight= " + minHeight);
            System.out.println("minIndex= " + i);
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }

    updateHeight();
    Thread.sleep(500);

}

public void updateHeight() {
    temp = RectHeight[counter];
    RectHeight[counter] = RectHeight[minIndex];
    RectList.get(counter).setHeight(RectHeight[counter]);

    RectHeight[minIndex] = temp;
    RectList.get(minIndex).setHeight(temp);


    counter++;
    minHeight = RectHeight[counter];
    minIndex = counter;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never sleep on the FX Application thread. That thread is responsible for rendering the UI, so by blocking it with `Thread.sleep()` you prevent the UI from being rendered, as you have observed.

Instead, use the [Animation API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/package-summary.html). A simple `Timeline` should work here:

```
@FXML
public void sort() {

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), e -> sort2()));
    timeline.setCycleCount(rectList.size());
    minHeight = rectHeight[0];
    counter = 0;
    minIndex = 0;
    temp = 0;

    timeline.play();


}

public void sort2() {
    System.out.println("start sort");

    System.out.println(minHeight);



    System.out.println("find min");
    for (int i = counter; i < (rectList.size()); i++) {
        System.out.println("i= " + i);
        if (rectHeight[i] < minHeight) {
            minHeight = rectHeight[i];
            System.out.println("minHeight= " + minHeight);
            System.out.println("minIndex= " + i);
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }

    updateHeight();

}

public void updateHeight() {
    temp = rectHeight[counter];
    rectHeight[counter] = rectHeight[minIndex];
    rectList.get(counter).setHeight(rectHeight[counter]);

    rectHeight[minIndex] = temp;
    rectList.get(minIndex).setHeight(temp);


    counter++;
    minHeight = rectHeight[counter];
    minIndex = counter;

}
```